# How to obtain global step when using tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, save

When we specify the global_step in the `Saver.save`, it will store the global_step as the checkpoint suffix.

```
# save the checkpoint
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session, checkpoints_path, global_step)
```

We can restore the checkpoint and obtain the last global step stored in the checkpoints like this:

```
# restore the checkpoint and obtain the global step
saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
...
_, gstep = session.run([optimizer, global_step], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
```

If we use `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, what is the equivalent way to save the global step to the checkpoint and obtain `gstep`?

### Edit 1

Followed by Maxim's suggestion, I have created the `global_step` variable before  `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`, and added a `CheckpointSaverHook` like this:

```
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
save_checkpoint_hook = tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir=checkpoints_abs_path,
                                                    save_steps=5,
                                                    checkpoint_basename=(checkpoints_prefix + ".ckpt"))

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                       is_chief=is_chief,                     
                                       hooks=[sync_replicas_hook, save_checkpoint_hook],
                                       config=config) as session:

    _, gstep = session.run([optimizer, global_step], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
    print("current global step=" + str(gstep))
```

I can see that it generates the checkpoint files similar to what `Saver.saver` does. However, it is unable retrieve the global step from the checkpoint. Please kindly advise how should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current global step via [`tf.train.get_global_step()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_global_step) or via [`tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_or_create_global_step) function. The latter should be called before training starts.

For the monitored session, add [`tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointSaverHook) to the `hooks`, which internally uses the defined global step tensor to save the model after every N steps.

Comment: I have made an edit to the original post which explains I am unable to retrieve the global_step. Please can you kindly have a look?